# Macbook M1 Apache seems to be always running

Tags: macos, apache, port, apple-m1

It seems like there's some kind of apache is always running on my Macbook with M1 Pro chip. It always shows "It works!" page on by the localhost address with no ability to change it. Even if I run `sudo apachectl stop` - it's still running, taking my 80 port. Can I stop it somehow? I can't really create any virtual host because of that

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, type

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

find out which app (may not be the Apache Server) is listening on TCP 127.0.0.1:80 and then stop/kill it.